# Position View X Y and translate animation to an Original location

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to do an animation where the small circle goes to the next screen as soon as it is clicked. I have a custom list view, with two text views. One of the textview is in circle background.

[image]

Now on click event for listitem the following code is triggered :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                int[] location = new int[2];
                holder.initialView.getLocationInWindow(location);
                intent.putExtra("location", location);
                intent.putExtra("initialText", holder.initialView.getText());
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

In the above code I am getting the location in windows of initialTextView, i.e. with circle background, and then pass the same to DetailActivity.

Inside of detailActivity, OnResume, I have the following code:

```
private TextView mInitialTextView;
private String mInitialText;
private int[] listItemLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    listItemLocation = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("location");
    mInitialText = getIntent().getStringExtra("initialText");

    mInitialTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.initial);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mInitialTextView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            mInitialTextView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            float x = location[0];
            float y = location[1];
            mInitialTextView.setX(listItemLocation[0]);
            mInitialTextView.setY(listItemLocation[1]);
            mInitialTextView.setText(mInitialText);
            mInitialTextView.animate().translationX(x)
                    .translationY(y).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(100);
        }
    });

}
```

DetailActivity - Layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.architectpack.animate.DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/initial"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AM"

        android:background="@drawable/circle_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, it not working. It is not calculating positions correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: tried to `Log.d` the value of `location` in both Activities?

Comment: @pskink Yes, the values are passing correct. However animation is completely going of of way. Firstly the circle starts from  wrong place and the animation does not ends on top. So basically setX or setY is not working as expectd.

Comment: and what are you doing with "location" extra in second Activity?

Comment: @pskink If you are referring             mInitialTextView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
 then that means I am reading the original location of the text view that I want to end my transition. so basically I bring the original item from position A to position B. The position B is send by ListView. So I want my TextView of DetailActivity to be at Position B, and then start animation till  Position A, which an original position. Hence to give x , y, I am find corresponding position of my DetailActivity TextView store it to pass translationX(x)...(y) . I have updated my above code.

Comment: see [this](http://codeshare.io/A6qg3)

Comment: @pskink thanks let me check this in the morning - It seems like the problem with my code, after look at yours, is that I have got parent on detail activity. I have modified my post with the activity xml as well.

Comment: @pskink Thank you very much for fixing this for me. So the key was  tv.setTranslationY(startloc[1] - loc[1]); Can you please put that in your answer ?